# $H$ must contain every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be a prime factor of the order of a finite group $G$. If $H$ is a normal subgroup $G$ whose index is not a multiple of $p$, show that $H$ must contain every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Show that $H$ must contain a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.
2. Show that $H$ contains all the subgroups of $G$ that are conjugates of $P$.

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I want to follow. but I don't know how to go through both of these

Comment: For 1, consider a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @rubin: The idea underlying step 1 is that in this case a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Can you see why?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $N$ is normal in $G$, then $N$ contains every element of $G$ that has order coprime to $[G:N]$.